# Docker 環境で php artisan migrate がうまく行かない

Tags: php, macos, docker, laravel, docker-compose

Macでlaravel,vue.js,docker（ローカルではdockerにnginxを使用）を使用してローカルでWEBアプリを制作しています。.envの設定がおかしいからだとは思いますが、dbとして使用しているローカルのmysqlに繋がらず、そのために `php artisan migrate` がエラーとなって詰まってしまっています。どこの設定が間違っているためにmysqlに繋がらないのかを知りたいのですがよろしくお願いします。

###　追記
マルチポストしていることを説明し忘れました。内容は全く同じですが追記しておきたいと思います。
https://teratail.com/questions/dudp4gwhsdoz12

#### エラー

```
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# php artisan migrate        

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = sample and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known")
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=sample", "hoge", "777", [])
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

#### 追記

コメントで助言されたのを試したところプロセスがうまく実行できていないことまでわかりました。

```
% docker-compose ps
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
portfolio-app-1     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   app                 running             9000/tcp
portfolio-db-1      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  exited (1)          
portfolio-web-1     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   web                 running             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

#### 追記２

% docker-compose logs db  の結果、'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'がおかしいとのことです。

```
% docker-compose logs db
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:29:56+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:29:57+09:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
portfolio-db-1  |   command was: mysqld --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.Ef2AJ4XEgw
portfolio-db-1  |   2022-03-05T10:29:57.143207+09:00 0 [ERROR] Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05T10:29:57.148263+09:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % 



docker/mysql/my.cnfの部分にこの記述、 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'　があります

portfolio/docker/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
user=mysql
character_set_server = utf8mb4
//この部分
collation_server = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

# timezone
default-time-zone = SYSTEM
log_timestamps = SYSTEM

# Error Log
log-error = mysql-error.log

# Slow Query Log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1.0
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0

# General Log
general_log = 1
general_log_file = mysql-general.log

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

またthinkerで環境変数を確認したところ一部反映されてないようでここにも原因がありそうです。

```
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio %  docker-compose exec app bash  
root@7b0ccf8be086:/var/www/html# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.11.1 (PHP 7.4.1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>>  env('DB_HOST');
=> "db"
>>> env('WEB_PORT');
=> null
>>> env('DB_PORT');
=> "3306"
>>> env('DB_HOSTURL');
=> null
>>> env('DB_NAME');
=> null
>>> env('DB_USER');
=> null
>>> env('DB_PASSWORD');
=> "777"
>>> env('DB_ROOT_PASSWORD');
=> null
>>>
```

バージョン
php: 7.4.1
laravel: 6.20.
MySQL version: 8.0.28

docker, docker-compose.yml は以下のページを参考に利用。

[絶対に失敗しないDockerでLaravel+Vueの実行環境（LEMP環境）を構築する方法〜前編〜](https://qiita.com/shimotaroo/items/29f7878b01ee4b99b951)

```
portfolio($docker-compose up -dをここで起動)
├─ docker
│    ├─ php
│    │   └─ Dockerfile
│    │   └─ php.ini
│    ├─ nginx
│    │    └─ Dockerfile
│    │    └─ default.conf
│    └─ mysql
│         └─ Dockerfile
│         └─ my.cnf
│
├─ src(laravelのapp、config,resousesや.env等が入っています)
│    
│ 
│─ .env(下)
│─ .gitignore   
└─ docker-compose.yml(下)
```

portfolio/.env

```
WEB_PORT=80
DB_PORT=3306
//docker-compose.yml内のdb
DB_HOSTURL=db
DB_NAME=sample
DB_USER=hoge
DB_PASSWORD=777
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

portfolio/src/.env

```
APP_NAME=docker-laravel-vue
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=省略
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=127.0.0.1

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sample
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# Composeファイルのバージョン
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  mysql-volume:

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOSTURL}
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

# web_serverでも可
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

追記
src/config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
]) : [],
],
```

ターミナルに打ち込んだ時に得られる情報

localのmysql詳細

```
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % pwd
/Users/masa/Desktop/portfolio

masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % mysql -u hoge -p sample;
Enter password: 
//『777』を入力
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 27
Server version: 8.0.28 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.


mysql> select user( );
+----------------+
| user( )        |
+----------------+
| hoge@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| sample             |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| sample     |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> use sample;
Database changed
mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| sample     |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % mysql -u root -p             
Enter password: 
//『secret』を入力
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 30
Server version: 8.0.28 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

実際の `php artisan migrate` がうまく行かない部分の詳細

```
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % mysql.server restart 
Shutting down MySQL
. SUCCESS! 
Starting MySQL
.. SUCCESS! 
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % docker-compose down          
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Container portfolio-db-1   Removed                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 ⠿ Container portfolio-web-1  Removed                                                                                                                                                                  0.3s
 ⠿ Container portfolio-app-1  Removed                                                                                                                                                                  0.3s
 ⠿ Network portfolio_default  Removed                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio %  docker builder prune &  docker volume prune
[1] 17257
WARNING! This will remove all local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] WARNING! This will remove all dangling build cache. Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] 
Total reclaimed space: 0B
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % docker-compose up -d                       
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Network portfolio_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 ⠿ Container portfolio-app-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                  4.3s
 ⠿ Container portfolio-db-1   Started                                                                                                                                                                  1.4s
 ⠿ Container portfolio-web-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                  5.1s
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % docker-compose exec app bash    
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# pwd
/var/www/html
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# ls -a
.   .editorconfig  .env.testing    .gitignore         .styleci.yml  app  bootstrap  composer.lock  database      package-lock.json  phpunit.xml  resources  server.php  tests   webpack.mix.js
..  .env       .gitattributes  .phpunit.result.cache  README.md artisan  composer.json  config         node_modules  package.json   public       routes storage     vendor
         
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# php artisan config:cache 
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# php artisan config:clear 
Configuration cache cleared!
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# php artisan cache:clear 
Application cache cleared!
root@8be8ddaa6767:/var/www/html# php artisan migrate        

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = sample and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known")
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=sample", "hoge", "777", [])
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/dudp4gwhsdoz12) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。マルチポストなるものを初めて知りました。今回が初めてなのでわざわざリンク等貼っていただいたり大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます‍♂️

Comment: エラーを見る限りホストが正しく解決できてなさそうです。`docker-compose up -d` のあと `docker-compose ps` でプロセスが起動しているかを確認してください（結果も貼り付けてもらえると）。またdockerプロセス内でtinkerを利用してDB_HOSTの値を確認すると良いかもしれません

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りプロセスが起動していないようです。　% docker-compose psをしたところportfolio-db-1      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  exited (1)     のようにPortがないことから確かにプロセスが正しく起動してないと思われます。

Comment: またthinkerの方も試してみたのですが追記のようになりました。所々nullになっているのでプロセスが正しく起動してないのかもしれません。

Comment: % docker-compose psの方も追記に載せておきたいと思います

Comment: `docker-compose logs db` をした場合何か出力されますか？またホストOS（Mac）でもmysqlが起動していませんか？ポートが被っているためdockerで起動できないケースに見えます

Comment: %　docker-compose logs dbの方も追記２に載せておきたいと思います。

Comment: 確認したところWebアプリ内ではversion5.7を扱っているのに対してlocalではversion８系を使っていることが原因かもしれません。version８で mysql.server restart をして試してみたいと思います

Comment: mysqlのversion５.７でそろえて mysql.server restart を試してみたのですがそちらの方は関係なく、＄docker-compose logs dbは依然として'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'でエラーになりました。

Comment: 解決しました！原因と解決法を載せておきたいと思います。sugamuraさん、ありがとうございました‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

`docker-compose logs db` の実行結果

```
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:29:56+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:29:57+09:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
portfolio-db-1  |   command was: mysqld --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.Ef2AJ4XEgw
portfolio-db-1  |   2022-03-05T10:29:57.143207+09:00 0 [ERROR] Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05T10:29:57.148263+09:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

のように 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' でエラーとなるので

[(Resolved) Unknown collation: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci](https://tecadmin.net/resolved-unknown-collation-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/)

のサイトを参考にdocker内を
COLLATION を'utf8_general_ci'
CHARACTER を'utf8'
に変更したところ

（docker/mysql/my.cnfの部分にこの記述、 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'　があるのでコードを載せておきたいと思います↓）

portfolio/docker/mysql/my.cnf（元々）

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
character_set_server = utf8mb4

collation_server = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

# timezone
default-time-zone = SYSTEM
log_timestamps = SYSTEM

# Error Log
log-error = mysql-error.log

# Slow Query Log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1.0
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0

# General Log
general_log = 1
general_log_file = mysql-general.log

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

改めて `docker-compose logs db` を実行した結果、以下のようにエラーメッセージが変わりました。

```
masa@MasaakinoMacBook-Air portfolio % 
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:58:18+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05 10:58:18+09:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
portfolio-db-1  |   command was: mysqld --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.u6hnMzU23j
portfolio-db-1  |   2022-03-05T10:58:18.873878+09:00 0 [ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
portfolio-db-1  | 2022-03-05T10:58:18.876518+09:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

'utf8_general_ci' は CHARACTER 'utf8mb4' に対して有効でないため
laravel内、およびdocker内の全てを
COLLATION を'utf8_general_ci'
CHARACTER を'utf8'
に統一すると `php artisan migrate` が通りました。解決できました。ありがとうございました！‍♂️